# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to allow users to add ratings to the books they have read. I am using `"@angular/material": "^7.3.0"` and `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.2".`

I have imported the following in my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ListComponent } from './components/list/list.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './components/registration/registration.component';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

I have added NgbModule to my imports,

```
imports: [
    ....,
    NgbModule
  ],
```

I am trying to show the ratings in my list.component.html. The list.component.ts looks like this,

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
// other code here
  currentRate = 8;
}
```

I have imports in list.component.ts but none related to the rating implementation.

The list.component.html for the rating implementation looks like this,

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="rating">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Rating</th>
    <td mat-cell>
      <ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate"></ngb-rating>
      <pre>Rate: <b>{{currentRate}}</b></pre>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

I am trying to implement this by following the Basic demo example provided at [ng-bootstrap rating](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples). The form headers are displayed but no data is shown. The error is

```
core.js:15714 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'template' of undefined
```

It has something to do with the rating implementation i am attempting as the form was working fine previously. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'template of undefined error' is associated with HTML.Please check your opening closing bracket as well.

Comment: Could you post the full HTML for your `list.component.html` file? Looks like it's been shortened.

Comment: Yes @Edric I have shortened it. The snippet of code I have put in the post is the only new addition. Nothing else has changed. I am trying to figure out how to show the rating stars under a column called ratings.

Comment: This error will come if any typo errors for the field names of mat table. In my case *matCellDef was *matCrllDef

Answer (score 0):

I added the `*matCellDef` and inserted the selector for the rating component. So I can see the rating component now but the visual representation is not quite the same as in the example. I will post another question for that.

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="rating">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Rating</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <app-rating></app-rating>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```